# XPath provided by Google Chrome incorrect

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, xpath, html-agility-pack, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to parse this website http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/financials?query=income-statement.  I am trying to get the value 50,175,000.  It is the Total Revenue row in the 12/31/2012 column.

Google Chrome provides the XPath if you go to Tools and then Developer Tools and right click on the node.  The original Xpath was `//*[@id="financials-iframe-wrap"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]`

I changed the double quotes to singles so now I have this `//*[@id='financials-iframe-wrap']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3].`

But when I try and use this XPath I get this error message `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Nasdaq Parsing Test.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is a larger portion of my code:

```
Dim Total_Revenue = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='financials-iframe-wrap']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")
                TextBox_Total_Revenue.Text = Total_Revenue.InnerText
```

Any advice would be appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google spreadsheet xpath only selects arrays instead of single values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317614/google-spreadsheet-xpath-only-selects-arrays-instead-of-single-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `//*[@id='financials-iframe-wrap']/div/table//tr[2]/td[3]` (I have removed `tbody` part)