# Google spreadsheet xpath only selects arrays instead of single values

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

So I am trying to use this bit of code to only select a single show from a show database, I only want the latest selected show, but google spreadsheet keeps returning an array of the lastest show from every season.

```
=importXML("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid="&B2, "//episode[number(translate(airdate, '-', '')) < "&I2&"][last()]")
```

B2 is the show id = 11215 and I2 is the today's date in iso style format = 20130626 this date is acquired from google spreadsheet with the command `=TEXT( TODAY() ; "yyyyMMdd" )`
So can anyone help me get just the latest show for the current season?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put parentheses around the first path of your XPath expression:

```
(//episode[number(translate(airdate, '-', '')) < "&I2&"])[last()]
```